# Accessing a simple txt file inside webroot in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting

My cakePHP application generates a simple text file inside the webroot directory.

I tried to access it by typing `http://<my own domain>/simple.txt` into my browser, but the application index page was shown up, not my text file.

How can I make this text file directly accessible?
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add it as an extension to parse:

```
Router::parseExtensions('txt');
```

Then, create a connection route:

```
Router::connect('/simple.txt', array('controller' => 'examplecontroller', 'action' => 'simple');
```

Now you will control the output of `http://yourproject.com/simple.txt` inside `simple()` method inside `examplecontroller` and in `simple.ctp` view.

It's not the way exactly you specified, but it works for sure and it's done the "cake way"

Comment: `My cakePHP application *generates* a simple text file` implies that the content of the file is dynamic, not static

Answer (score 3):

### Only the webroot is web-accessible

Taking a guess, you have the following structure (or similar):

```
docroot
    app
        Config/
        Controller/
        Model/
        Plugin/
        Test/
        tmp/
        View/
        webroot/
    lib/
    ...
    simple.txt
```

That file `simple.txt` is *inaccessible* to a browser. The reason is, assuming mod_rewrite is enabled, that all requests are rewritten to be `foo` -> `app/webroot/foo` by the top-level .htaccess file.

To make the file accessible just put it in the webroot:

```
docroot
    app
        Config/
        Controller/
        Model/
        Plugin/
        Test/
        tmp/
        View/
        webroot/
            simple.txt <- moved
    lib/
    ...
```

Note that if this is the problem, you've got a [development install](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#development) - it would be a better idea to use a production install (make your webserver point at the webroot folder, not the root of your whole application).

Answer (score -1):

these url ://simple.txt seems wrong to me. It should be like :

://yourhost/yourproject/simple.txt

I generally can access it in these manner on my local cake php project.

Comment: Would be nice, but this txt is act like a sitemap.txt, so it has to be there in the //myhost/simple.txt path.

Comment: you should add a link to these file from the robots.txt file in the root directory of your project.

Comment: Ok, the main headache  here is that any of the files inside webroot can not be accessed directly. If I place here anything via ftp I can not access it directly...annoying. I suspected the .htaccess file may be responsible for this, but I am not sure. And in addition, on localhost, this files can be accessed directly, but after I upload my project to the server, they are unaccessible. I'm confused.

Comment: if you _are_ putting the files in the webroot the .htaccess file is not a factor, you can temporarily delete it to demonstrate. There are really only 2 possibilities that come to mind for your question: 1) the files _don't_ exist 2) apache doesn't have permission to read the files.